# Unable to run project in Android Studio (libGDX)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, libgdx

Every time I try to run my Desktop project in Android Studio, I instantly get the following error:

```
Error:com.android.tools.idea.gradle.util.Projects.lastGradleSyncFailed(Lcom/intellij/openapi/project/Project;)Z
```

No gradle build happens, or any sort of syncing. Android Studio just jumps straight to this error.

I have restart/invalidated caches, I have deleted my .gradle folder in both project and home locations, I have reinstalled android studio, I have created a new project, but I still get the same error.

When I run the gradle build manually, the build completes successfully. I can even run the Android project with no problems. It is just the Desktop project that is giving me problems.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

I am using the latest version of android gradle (2.3.0), and my JDK is the correct version (1.8).

I am getting this error after updating to Android Studio 2.3.

To clarify, the Gradle build/sync completes SUCCESSFULLY.

Comment: sounds like your desktop project might be mislinked or entering project at the wrong level

Comment: syncing of gradle is failed so there is a gradle error ?? what is it ?

Comment: @AbhishekAryan Syncing of gradle does not fail. That is the problem. I do not know why I am getting this error, since nothing is wrong.

Comment: have you tried Build-> rebuild project

Comment: disable the RoboVM plugin.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**UPDATE:** It looks like this issue may have been fixed in RoboVM 2.3.2: https://github.com/MobiVM/robovm/issues/115#issuecomment-303979058

---

It sounds like you may need to revert back to Android Studio 2.2, which you can download here: http://tools.android.com/download/studio/builds/android-studio-2-2-3

I had the same problem. The error message in "Messages" isn't helpful, but if you go to `Help->Show Log in Finder`, you'll see some extra information that's a little more useful:

```
2017-03-06 17:52:27,615 [4546022]   INFO - ij.compiler.impl.CompileDriver - java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.android.tools.idea.gradle.util.Projects.lastGradleSyncFailed(Lcom/intellij/openapi/project/Project;)Z
    at org.robovm.idea.components.RoboVmBuildProcessParametersProvider.getVMArguments(RoboVmBuildProcessParametersProvider.java:60)
    at com.intellij.compiler.server.BuildManager.launchBuildProcess(BuildManager.java:1136)
    at com.intellij.compiler.server.BuildManager.lambda$null$11(BuildManager.java:730)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor.runFirstTaskThenPollAndRunRest(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:178)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor.access$000(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:40)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$2.run(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:197)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

It turns out RoboVm isn't compatible with Android Studio 2.3 (yet): https://github.com/MobiDevelop/robovm/issues/115

After I went back to Android Studio 2.2.3, I could run the Desktop application just fine.

Comment: Is true, that's also happening using Multi-OS Engine

Comment: Please, where can I find older versions of Android studio? That link does not work anymore.

Comment: I honestly don't know :/ Seems like they accidentally deleted/moved them.

I've since moved on to Unity. It has a lot of active support behind it, so very unlikely to run into issues like this.

Comment: Does this still happen? I mean, isn't RoboVM compatible yet with Android Studio 2.3 (I use 2.3.3)? I'm trying to find the Android Studio 2.2 (any of it's versions) but can't make it to find a link that is working.

Comment: I haven't tried yet, but according to the GitHub Issue referenced above, they pushed a fix on May 25: https://github.com/MobiVM/robovm/issues/115#issuecomment-303979058

Which might be available in RoboVM 2.3.2 (at time of this comment, only available as a snapshot build)